# Is the phrase 南狩之志，乃大得也 ironically ?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, literary-chinese

A random phrase from 周易 is 南狩之志，乃大得也. I tried to translate it using the following thoughts.

- 乃 is probably a conjunction and renders to "in fact, actually" to stress something not as expected.
- 大得 rendered to "big gain, big achievement"
- 志 rendered to "will, determination,intention"
- 狩   is somehow problematic, I found "to go for a hunt in the winter", 
     but I am not sure, if it only is limited to "winterhunting".

So, my translation is:

**The determination to hunt in the winter in the south is actually a big achievement.**

I am not sure if I got the sentence verbatim right, but if it is so , is the sentence irony or sarcasm, because winter hunting in the south is considered paradoxically? like saying "gone fishing to the sahara"

Answer (score 1):

狩 is to hunt, and has nothing to with the season.

*The aspiration to hunt in the south brought success.*

Then we may ask why, and the answer is that the south is lighter in the winter than the north. So the season is indirectly the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 狩, @倪阔乐 's answer is not correct.

According to explaination from http://www.zdic.net/z/1e/js/72E9.htm , it means hunting in winter, and especially means burn woods to force animals run away indeed easy for hunting.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you quoted is actually explaining/supplementing the sentence "明夷于南狩，得其大首，不可疾貞。" which means (approximately) "to go south to for war, capturing/killing the bad leader, in a righteous manner".

As a result, such "志" is considered "大得".